# MYSQL Procedure and Trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to create 1 procedure and 1 trigger which both logs insert of a car in Car-table: car(reg_nr, color, brand). I have created the trigger like this:

```html
Create table CarLog(
     ID integer,
     User varchar (32),
     Primary key (ID)
)engine=innodb;
```

```html
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER CarsLog AFTER INSERT ON Car 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO CarLog(User) values ( user() ) ;
END;
//
 
DELIMITER ;
```

But how do I create a procedure which does the same thing as the trigger above?

Comment: There is no such thing as an after insert procedure. If you don't know how to create a procedure please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Why do you want this available as a procedure AND as a trigger ? There is not enough context to your question to give a proper answer